# Is heat a practical way to kill structual mold?

Tags: mold

So heating the whole house or affected rooms up to 45 50 degrees C for long enough to also heat and kill any mold in exterior walls as well as mold on the surface?

Comment: what is `structural mold`? ... is that a mold that is keeping your house from collapsing?

Comment: why don't you ask here instead? https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What has caused the mold - if you don’t treat that then it will return.

Comment: Actually, *cold* is used to remove mold, e.g. https://backtonormalrestoration.com/calabash-restoration-services/dry-ice-cleaning/ , but as mentioned, it only removes *surface* mold.

Comment: All natural wood products are full of mold spores with dimensional lumber it is sprayed with a biocide after the finish cuts so it doesn’t turn black right away. Plywood is heated to cure the glue and this process kills the mold. Keeping the humidity low is the best way to keep mold from growing. First of all don’t panic most mold is not a “killer”.  Their are mold foggers, mold bombs if you want to kill surface mold but nothing you can do will totally eliminate mold spores from structural lumber.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Solar Mike. Sure, it might kill existing mold, by drying everything. But, it will reactivate if its cause isn't addressed...you may just need to run the air conditioner or exhaust fans more often or plug-in a dehumidifier.

Although, is there a concern? Not really. Mold is literally everywhere and in every breath you take and run-of-the-mill mold concealed in walls has no effect on people nor building products.

Now, if you mean **Black Mold** that's even showing up inside rooms in little patches. Then, you really MUST rip out the walls and professionally remediate it from the property.

**Black Mold** is EXTREMELY serious and also means you have a very blatant construction problem or water leak that's been ignored too long. In order to avoid PERMANENT health problems the issue(s) must be fixed entirely and ASAP.

Comment: There are non toxic black mold even Stachybotrys the bad boy of molds is not always toxic , I live in Oregon and we have all kinds of different mold(s) a mold fogger will kill surface molds . I just use 3%hydrogen peroxide and water. So many people have been scared by black mold when most household molds are black and not toxic testing is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Point well taken. I wouldn't doubt there's a dozen black molds of toxic and not. But, to just wipe off what's visible or only kill what can be killed (not getting much inside walls & insulation) doesn't fix anything nor does it stop damage or health problems...what's the "joy" of that fogger stuff, I wouldn't want it anymore than the mold. A multitude of cases of exceedingly sick people ultimately revealed mold behind their pristine walls to be the cause of their symptoms and even permanent conditions. So, even the non-disturbance safety claim is debunked when it comes to certain molds.

Comment: I agree there are some that are more sensitive, just like nut allergies, shellfish and some that say they are allergic to emf.  So anything is possible.

Comment: Even if it's not toxic, the house crumbling on top of you because the leak that caused the mold also made the wood structure rot and snap is kind of a problem too ;)